# Delete specific history in verioned tables?

Tags: database, mariadb, database-administration

I'm using MariaDB 10.3. Is there a way to delete history for a specific record? I have a situation where once I delete a record, I'm under contract to remove all records (including historical ones).

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_trxid` bigint(20) unsigned GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START,
  `end_trxid` bigint(20) unsigned GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`end_trxid`),
  PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (`start_trxid`, `end_trxid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING
```

And consider the following commands run against that table:

```
insert into users (name, email) values ('cory', 'name@corycollier.com'), ('bob', 'bob@gmail.com');
UPDATE users set name='Cory' where id=1;
UPDATE users set name='Cory Collier' where id=1;
UPDATE users set name='Cory C' where id=1;
UPDATE users set name='Cory' where id=1;
```

That leaves me with the following history:

```
select * from (select * from users FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) and (NOW())) as history where id=1;
+----+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------+----------------------+
| id | name         | email                       | start_trxid | end_trxid            |
+----+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------+----------------------+
|  1 | cory         | corycollier@corycollier.com |      697377 |               697384 |
|  1 | Cory Collier | corycollier@corycollier.com |      697384 |               697391 |
|  1 | Cory C       | corycollier@corycollier.com |      697391 |               697394 |
|  1 | Cory         | corycollier@corycollier.com |      697394 |               697401 |
```

I don't have a way to delete history for that user. I'd like to.

Comment: "I don't have a way to delete history for that user. I'd like to."
What does that mean? You should be able to execute a `DELETE` query? What happens when you attempt to `DELETE` them?

Comment: `I'm under contract to remove all records (including historical ones)` then your historical record is not reliable. In this sense , it is not correct.